# Input with shifting label field ( in all CSS) without required

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a floating label for a styled input done with all CSS. The problem I am having is that this requires the input to have the `required` property in order to manage the moving label ( with pure CSS). I am wondering if it's possible to do this without the `required` field because putting this in certain forms is messing with the form validations. My markup and CSS looks like so :

```
.myInput {
  position: relative;
  input {
    padding: 30px 10px 10px;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    &:focus {
      outline: none;
    }
    &:focus~label,
    &:valid~label,
    &:placeholder-shown~label {
      top: 10px;
      color: black;
    }
  }
  label {
    color: red;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    left: 10px;
    top: 20px;
    transition: 0.2s ease all;
    -moz-transition: 0.2s ease all;
    -webkit-transition: 0.2s ease all;
  }
}



<div class="myInput">
  <input type="text" required id="target" />
  <label htmlFor="target">
        label
    </label>
</div>
```

You'll notice that if you remove the `required` the label no longer moves into the placeholder spot in an empty input. Here it is in a working fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/1ob2npcu/2/

I am trying to see if there is a way to do this purely in CSS - i am using SCSS if this helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remove the `required` attribute then also remove

```
&:valid~label
```

from the `CSS`: then you need to define a placeholder for the input and revert the logic for the `placeholder-shown` pseudoclass, so the SCSS style for the `input` becomes

```
input {
    padding: 30px 10px 10px;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;

    &::placeholder { 
       color: transparent;
    }

    &:focus {
        outline: none;
    }

    &:focus ~ label,
    &:not(:placeholder-shown) ~ label{
        top: 10px;
        color: black;
    }

}
```

also, the attribute in the label is `for` (not `htmlfor`)

> [fork on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6j4nshpg/1/)